# Как в js преобразовать массив объектов в объект?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

**Вот пример массива:**

```
  const myArray = [
    {
      data: {
        name: 'Alex',
        city: 'London',
        year: '1991',
      },
    },
    {
      data: {
        name: 'John',
        city: 'London',
        year: '1992',
      },
    },
    {
      data: {
        name: 'Alice',
        city: 'Paris',
        year: '1989',
      },
    },
    {
      data: {
        name: 'Romeo',
        city: 'Rome',
        year: '1990',
      },
    },
    {
      data: {
        name: 'Michael',
        city: 'London',
        year: '1989',
      },
    },
  ];
```

**Нужно получить:**

```
  const myObject = {
    London: [
      {
        data: {
          name: 'Alex',
          city: 'London',
          year: '1991',
        },
      },
      {
        data: {
          name: 'John',
          city: 'London',
          year: '1992',
        },
      },
      {
        data: {
          name: 'Michael',
          city: 'London',
          year: '1989',
        },
      },
    ],
    Paris: [
      {
        data: {
          name: 'Alice',
          city: 'Paris',
          year: '1989',
        },
      },
    ],
    Rome: [
      {
        data: {
          name: 'Romeo',
          city: 'Rome',
          year: '1990',
        },
      },
    ],
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Обычно, если из массива методом каких-то вычислений нужно получить не-массив (объект, число, строку и т.д.), пользуются [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Если оператор `??=` вам ещё незнаком, почитать можно тут: [Logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment). Его удобно использовать, когда вы коллекционируете какие-то данные в ключах объекта, чтобы задать начальное значение при создании контейнера.

```js
const myArray = [
    {
      data: {
        name: 'Alex',
        city: 'London',
        year: '1991',
      },
    },
    {
      data: {
        name: 'John',
        city: 'London',
        year: '1992',
      },
    },
    {
      data: {
        name: 'Alice',
        city: 'Paris',
        year: '1989',
      },
    },
    {
      data: {
        name: 'Romeo',
        city: 'Rome',
        year: '1990',
      },
    },
    {
      data: {
        name: 'Michael',
        city: 'London',
        year: '1989',
      },
    },
];

const myArrayByCity = myArray.reduce(
  (acc, object) => {
    const city = object.data.city;
    acc[city] ??= [];
    acc[city].push(object);
    return acc;
  },
  {},
);

console.log(JSON.stringify(myArrayByCity, null, '  '));
```

Comment: или если пойти дальше в однострочники: `myArray.reduce((acc, object) =>({...acc, [object.data.city]:(acc[object.data.city]??[]).concat(object)}), {})`

Comment: @Grundy Ну, если играть в программистский гольф, то да) Но будет неэффективно, потому что объект на каждом витке будет пересоздаваться с всё нарастающей итерацией по свойствам.

Comment: ага, но есть надежда, что что-то может быть оптимизировано.